# How to create folder name as drop down button and list files inside the selected directory as css3 cards?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am an absolute beginner to web development. I am creating a website that holds subject videos for different class students.

Like as below, 
Folder : Class 8 - > Subject - > English, Tamil, Maths.. English - > video1.mp4, video2.mp4, etc., 
Folder : Class 9 - > Subject - > English, Tamil, Maths

I have individual folders to each class and inside each class there are subject folders and in each subject there are video files.

** Folders as dropdown box, files as css3 cards **

I want to create dependent drop down boxes like if I select dropdown1 as class 8, it should display the subject folders name in dropdown2 then i will select the subject, the video files inside the selected subject folder should be displayed as css3 cards as like youtube mobile view and also responsive.

This is my first web based application so kindly help me to find the route to success.

And the important thing is I don't want to use database to save file location. It just display files as per the selection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“so kindly help me to find the route to success”_ - the journey starts here: [ask].

Comment: _“I want to create  […]”_ - so get started then. Try something, and then show us what you got, together with a proper problem description, if you can not get it done all by yourself. We can try and help you fix problems with code you have written, but we don’t write tutorials on-demand here.